# C++ Function output changes after return

Tags: c++

I am trying to get a vector of trees from a DFS traversal of a graph but the result changes after it is returned from the function.

This is the Tree class:

```
template <typename T>
class Tree
{
public:
    T v;    // value of current node
    // List of subtrees
    std::list<Tree<T>*> children;
    // Pointer to parent
    Tree<T> *parent;
    Tree(T v) {
        this->v = v;
    }
}
```

This is the relevant part of the function

```
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i)
        trees.push_back(Tree<T>(info[i]));

    int parent, node;
    std::vector<int> roots;
    for (int i = 0; i < V; ++i) {
        parent = parents[i];
        node = path[i];

        if (parent != -1) {
            trees[parent].children.push_back(&trees[node]);
            trees[node].parent = &trees[parent];
        }
        else {
            roots.push_back(node);
        }
    }
    for(int node_i : roots)
        res.push_back(trees[node]);
    return res;
```

and the variable declarations are these:

```
        template <typename T>
    std::vector<Tree<T>> DFSTree(std::vector<T> &info) {
    std::vector<Tree<T>> res;
    std::vector<int> path;
    std::vector<int> parents;
    std::vector<Tree<T>> trees;
```

The Tree within the resulting vectors' children don't have any children set.
Sorry if this is a basic question but I couldn't find an answer anywhere.
Thank you for the response

Comment: Could you include the entire function (meaning the name the return type and parameter list)?

Answer (score 0):

You have pointers in your `Tree` class.  When you copy the tree nodes with `res.push_back(trees[node])`, the child and parent pointers still point into `trees`, and not `res`.  When the function returns, `trees` goes out of scope and its memory is freed, leaving the pointers in `res` pointing at deleted memory.

The fix is to rethink your design so you don't use pointers.

Comment: You mean I should change the tree class so it doesn't use pointers?

Comment: @AndreiIacob That's one of the easier ways to deal with it.  Keeping the pointers requires _updating_ the pointers whenever a copy is made which may not be trivial.